# Not able to convert data to ng2-chart [ Bar Chart ]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, ng2-charts

I am new to angular and I am using Angular 7 and I need to convert my api data to the ng2-charts format.

Below is my api data:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Fetched Successfully",
    "data": [
      {
        "1": [
          {
            "productid": "5c595f1c736429312f1ee15b",
            "totalQty": 5
          },
          {
            "productid": "5c595f1c736429312f1ee158",
            "totalQty": 54
          },
          {
            "productid": "5c595f1c736429312f1ee157",
            "totalQty": 156
          }
        ],
        "2": [
          {
            "productid": "5c595e3b736429312f1ee155",
            "totalQty": 15
          },
          {
            "productid": "5c595f1c736429312f1ee157",
            "totalQty": 42
          }
        ],
        "5": [
          {
            "productid": "5c595e3b736429312f1ee155",
            "totalQty": 50
          },
          {
            "productid": "5c595f1c736429312f1ee157",
            "totalQty": 70
          }
        ],
        "12": [
          {
            "productid": "5c595e3b736429312f1ee145",
            "totalQty": 17
          },
          {
            "productid": "5c595f1c736429312f1ee157",
            "totalQty": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Below is my expected output format:

```
  public barChartLabels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']; // all months 
  public barChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;

  public barChartData = [ 
    { data: [5], label: '5c595f1c736429312f1ee15b' },
    { data: [54], label: '5c595f1c736429312f1ee158' },
    { data: [156, 42, , , 70, , , , , , , 5], label: '5c595f1c736429312f1ee157' },
    { data: [, 15, , , 50], label: '5c595e3b736429312f1ee155' },
    { data: [, , , , , , , , , , , 17], label: '5c595e3b736429312f1ee145' },
    { data: [, 15], label: '5c595e3b736429312f1ee145' }
  ];
```

I want to make chart dynamic because there will be dynamic data from the api.

I have tried using loops but it makes complexity more and takes time so looking for a efficient solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope this help : "https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/662"
this issue has been closed in the link above.